# Google cloud vision API, doesn't detect certain font

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to read title numbers and VIN of california and pennsylvania titles, but the VISION API, detects them improperly.
The image is 300 dpi image.

example:

[image]

[image]

numbers 6 and 1 in image are returned as b and L, respectively.

So, can we do anything to get the image text right.
This situation doesnt appear when dealing other states titles, as they use regular font. Any help is greatly appreciated.